# Mapping “event” series, with segments of variable length, to time series for loss calculation

Tags: time-series, sequence

I have a time series of data which I map to a time series of non-exclusive binary features (in my case, short-time audio spectrograms to features of the audio). I will refer to a collection of these classes that remains roughly constant over some time as “event”.

For example, my audio stream might contain the word “leave”, so my time series of classes might contain

```
l-sound   00000000000011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
vowel     00000000000000000000011111111111111111110000000000000000000000000
fricative 00000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000
high      00000000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000
noise     00011111010000000000000000000000000000000000000111111100000000000
```

which correspond to – taking into account that transitions beween events may be noisy – the events sequence

```
l-sound   00010000
vowel     00001000
fricative 00000100
high      00001000
noise     01000010
```

All of these features are binary and not mutually exclusive, and every (realized) combination of features corresponds to one label, so if `#` stood for exactly the feature set `{noise}`, `i` for `{high, vowel}` and `ʎ` for `{l-sound, high}` etc., the columns of this event sequence might be given as the string `_#_liv#_`.

I have vastly more target data in this compressed, event-centered string format, a lot more than I have time-series of binary feature vectors. Because the mapping from event sequence to time series is just a somewhat noisy stretching of the data, probably even with characteristic lengths for each event, my intuition suggests that there should be a better, more deterministic way to use this data than making a `seq2seq` learn its internal structure.

- I have tried to build a separate calculation graph that maps a set of lengths to differences of sigmoid functions, in order to obtain differentiable functions that approximate interval characteristic functions (`0011110000` etc.), hoping that an optimizer might be able to shift the boundaries towards the actual ranges. It does not look promising.

Given that my model currently produces time-series data, but I have a lot of event-sequence data, how can I best use my event-sequence data to train the model?

Comment: If there is standard term for my “events”, please feel free to edit and tag my post accordingly.

Comment: In your example event sequence *\_#\_liv#\_*, which label does *i* correspond to? At that position both *vowel* and *high* is *1*. Could you clarify in your event sequence, it is allowed to have more than one *1*'s at each timestamp?

Comment: @user12075 Yes, those binary features are not mutually exclusive. Have I clarified that bit well enough?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about some edit distance based loss function, like the CTC, if the features were mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ah, CTC sounds like an excellent starting point, though. If it's based on edit distance and alignment algorithms, there may be a way to use my binary feature vector to construct a more fine-grained mismatch cost matrix, than just “classes match” or “classes don't match”, and then apply a modified version of CTC.